# Java has too many level symbolic links

Tags: java, linux, file

Well,I was trying to install forge on my linux machine(Kali-Linux).While on the was I was and still am unable to access the forge file(.jar).Due to an issue in which there is a lack of a  command called "java".

The current problem I am having is `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java 1` while using this command I get a response as `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/bin/java': Too many levels of symbolic links.`
When I try to ls in the ***/bin***.The java symbolic link has a weird symbol(Just wanted to mention it cause it looked weird) [image: a response by the ls command.]

Is there anyway to fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /bin/java`.

Comment: There you go,I have edited the post

Comment: And where does `/etc/alternatives/java` point?

Comment: By the way, it's a bit unusual to have `java` in `/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`. I don't think that's normal on Debian-based systems, so maybe that's part of the problem. Did you tinker with it manually?

Comment: /etc/alternatives/java doesn't point anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "too many levels of symbolic links" message means that 40 symlinks have been traversed in attempting to resolve a path to an object.

It nearly always happens because you have a symlink that directly or indirectly points to itself.  And the purpose of the limit (and the check) is to prevent the kernel going into an infinite loop.

So, why it is it happening here?  Well, it is not entirely clear.  But it seems like an earlier `update-alternatives` run has left some "wreckage" in the form of bad symlinks.  If "/bin/java" *already* points to "/etc/alternatives/java", then "/etc/alternatives/java" *should* be a symlink to ... somewhere else.

Try the following:

1. Use `update-alternatives --remove-all java` to clear out any alternatives for the `java` command.  (If this fails with the same problem, try step 2 first, then retry this step.   Adding `--force` might help too.)
2. Remove the "/bin/java" and "/usr/bin/java" symlinks if they still exist.
3. Make sure that you have actually installed Java (already!), and "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java" is the correct path for the executable.  Run `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java -version` to check.
4. Run `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java 1`.

Note that `update-alternatives` does not actually install anything.  For the command to work properly, you need to have installed (in this case) a Java JRE or JDK or a Kali Java package *already*.

Note that it cannot do any real harm to remove "alternatives" symlink chains that are broken.  You can always clean them out and rebuild them.  (By hand, if necessary.)  The alternatives mechanism is just a fancy way of managing symlinks.

Comment: Uhm,the first command you said to use has a response of ```update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/bin/java': Too many levels of symbolic links``` I'm confused.

Comment: So,what If i delete the symbolic links first? and go for removing the java alternatives?

Comment: You can't do any real damage.  They are only symlinks.  Also, try using the `--force` option as well.  And if that doesn't help, add `--debug` as well.

Comment: Hey,I tried to rm the symlink first and guess what? IT WORKED :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I'm putting it here with a clear explanation.
When you use this command `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java 1` to update java, there is already a symbolic-link of java file between these 3 directories /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java and-> /lib/jvm/jdk-current-version/bin/java.

For updating alternatives first you need to remove the symbolic link at /lib/jvm/jdk-current-version/bin/java. Which will ultimately remove all links. Then you need to remove the java file from /usr/bin/java and /etc/alternatives/java.
Then run the update-alternatives command.

In my case, I did the following commands

1. `rm symlink /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`
2. `update-alternatives --remove-all java` for removing the java file.
3. `rm /usr/bin/java` if java file still exits in /usr/bin
4. then run the command `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk-17.0.4.1+1/bin/java 100`
   or in your case it is `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java 1`.

This will install new version of java into /usr/bin from the jdk directory you specified and automatically symbolic-links all the java files.